# Female pug getting too excited

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations, toys

I own a female pug, who is one year and ten months old. She is acting too naughty recently: she digs into our blankets and jeans, bites sleeves--but only those of my 14 years old sister--and pulls them, and makes growling noises when she's chewing her favorite toy.

She does specific things with specific people. She fights with my sister (biting sleeves, digging) and loves my dad whenever he comes home.

The latter is quite a regular thing. She grabs her toy in her mouth and makes funny growls while looking at my dad. Whenever he holds her she goes away but then comes back.

**Is there a reason for both the cases above or is it something to be worried about?**

P.S She's intact but not currently in heat.

Comment: Ideally, you want the dog to be the lowest rank in the pack but it's hard to achieve specially with kids

Comment: [Update] She has started doing this with me too. I have observed its only me and my sister, not our parents, who are the victims of this. She scratches our arms, jeans, necks. Smells vigorously. And grabs sleeves and shakes them as if she wants to kill it. She does that for quite long. And sometimes if I force her to sit. she fights back.