# Female pug getting aggressive and jerking lower abdomen

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression, biting, scratching

My female pug almost 2 year old fights with any individual in the house except my father. She scratches the arms and bites the sleeves. If ignored, she makes crying sound and barks.

Sometimes she smells legs constantly and then stands on two legs with her front paws getting supported on our leg, and then she jerks her lower abdomen up and down.

Please help me, I am extremely new to dogs. I adopted her 5 months ago and we got happy along, but now she is being like this.

P.S. She was recently hurt by a German Shepherd, we got her injected with necessary injections and recently she was also given CCV vaccine.

Comment: The issue is the same as your previous question http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/female-pug-getting-too-excited the humans in your house need to become leaders to your dog. There is only one pack leader per pack but as long as all of you out rank the dog you will be fine. I suggest you do some research online to becoming a pack leader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is actually dominance behavior.  Yes, even female dogs will sometimes mount other dogs or human legs in order to show their dominance.  You need to completely and consistently ignore her undesirable behavior like scratching and biting, barking.  Establish a habit of shutting her in another room for say ten minutes when she does one of these undesirable behaviors.  The other room should be made to be comfortable for her, with toys and such.  The point is not punishment, it is to establish if she does one of these inappropriate things to get attention, she will get the opposite of attention.  If you stop responding to her desires whenever she has them, she may stop with the other dominance displays as well.  Also, if all else fails, get a professional trainer.